# Is it time-consuming to set TextView background as a drawable for the purpose of having round corners?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I find many online resources recommend to have a 9-patch file as the background of a TextView, in order to let the TextView have round corners.

But I think stretching an image file is time-consuming.

If we create a LinearLayout above the TextView, and have a one small left round corner drawable ImageView at the left, a right round corner drawable ImageView at the right.

Then put a TextView.

Then using a similar way to create a LinearLayout which show the bottom two corners.

Would this solution be a little better?

Comment: I feel this is a case of [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Using a 9-patch would be significantly easier and a more robust solution.

Comment: I'd say this is an *egregious* case of premature optimization. @.@ 

Test first, fix if you actually see a performance problem.

Comment: Now you have two more online sources recommending a 9-patch :)

Comment: Not to mention, I would expect that adding an additional layout and view to the hierarchy would be a net **loss** in performance as compared to just using the 9-patch.

Comment: Why don't you use xml to create a background with rounded corners? It reduces your app size and it's stretchable.

Comment: @Neil Also a good suggestion. :)

Comment: @Neil, I am not worried about app size now (actually we used xml). I am just thinking stretching an image (whether from xml or from an image file) might be time-consuming.

Answer (score 1):

I use mostly xml drawables to create my `Button` and `TextView` backgrounds, you simply add the `<corners` tag with attributes to add rounded corners to your background. If you're prepared to use this approach you can do something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:startColor="#BBBBBB" android:endColor="#CCCCCC" android:angle="270"    android:type="linear"/>

    <corners android:radius="5dp"/> <!-- gives your background rounded corners -->
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#60EEEEEE"/> <!-- creates a border around the image -->
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no fixed script to the user interface you may design it differently I may design differently.

Using 9-patch images is time comsuming as you need to create them first but they are really helpful but what I would prefer is to create a shape drawable and use it as textview background

like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <corners android:radius="10px"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" /> 
</shape>
```

and use this drawable as my textviews background

Answer (score 1):

Just for giggles, I put the following together for a performance test:

```
public class OverNineThousandPatchActivity extends Activity {
    boolean flag = false;

    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        setContentView(button);

        long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        long iterations = 100000;

        for (long i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            button.setBackgroundResource(flag ? R.drawable.panel_shadow : R.drawable.progress_overlay);
            flag = !flag;
        }

        long total = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        Log.d("OverNineThousand", "Total elapsed: " + total + " Individual: " + (total / iterations));
    }
}
```

Creates a View and then sets the background to two alternating nine-patch images 100,000 times in a row. Tried this over five different runs:

```
Total Time | Time Per setBackgroundResource()
           |
5,177 ms   | .05177 ms
4,793 ms   | .04793 ms
4,851 ms   | .04851 ms
4,957 ms   | .04957 ms
4,957 ms   | .04957 ms
```

Roughly 1/20th of a millisecond.

I wouldn't worry about it. ;)

(*Totally not a scientific test)

Comment: Thanks. Just a little wondering: I think setBackgroundResource does not measure the real time. Rendering is excuted somewhere else.

Comment: Pretty sure it's synchronous, actually, but yeah as I said, totally not scientific. :P